# ByteBuffer.capacity() vs ChannelBuffer.capacity()

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, netty, channel

I would like to know why when I wrap a ByteBuffer into a ChannelBuffer the capacity of this last changes.
For example I have this piece of code:

```
int BUFFER_SIZE = 10000;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect (BUFFER_SIZE);

SocketAddress address;
     try
     {
        address = datagramChannel.receive(buffer);
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
        //print warning
     }
     buffer.flip();

     System.out.println("1- Buffer size = "+ buffer.capacity ());

     ChannelBuffer chanBuffer = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(buffer);

     System.out.println("2- ChannelBuffer size = "+ chanBuffer.capacity ());
```

I will have as outputs:

> 1- Buffer size = 10000
>
> 2- ChannelBuffer size = 12

Comment: What is `ChannelBuffer`??

Comment: You received 12 bytes. The ChannelButfer clearly only contains the used portion of the ByteBuffer.